# Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $G(x,t)=t(x-1)$ when $t\leq x$ and $x(t-1)$ when $t\geq x$.

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

Let $f\colon[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $$G(x,t)=\begin{cases}t(x-1)&\text{when $t\leq x$,}\\x(t-1)&\text{when $t\geq x$.}\end{cases}$$ Let $$g(x)=\int_0^1f(t)G(x,t)\,\mathrm dt.$$ Show that $g''(x)$ exists and eqals $f(x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

---

I don't really know how handle this, the multiple variables confuse me.

Comment: Hint: $G(x+h,t)-G(x,t)$ is most of the time either $ht$ or $h(t-1)$

Comment: I see that but still don't understand how this helps. When I'm trying to calculate $g''(x)$ from $g(x)=\int_0^1f(t)G(x,t)dt$ I should differentiate with respect to $x$, right? But I'm having an integral which depends on $t$. Can I just differentiate inside the integral and do the actual integration later on?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $0<x<1$ we can rewrite the definition of $g$ as
$$\begin{align} g(x)&=\int_0^xf(t)t(x-1)\,\mathrm dt+\int_x^1f(t)(t-1)x\,\mathrm dt\\&=(x-1)\int_0^xtf(t)\,\mathrm dt+x\int_{x}^1(t-1)f(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=x\int_0^1(t-1)f(t)\,\mathrm dt+x\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^xtf(t)\,\mathrm dt\end{align}$$
Now that the (continuous) integrads do not depend on $x$ so that (per fundamental theorem) differentiation with respect to the integration limits is expressed by the integrand. Therefore,
$$\begin{align}g'(x)&=\int_0^1(t-1)f(t)\,\mathrm dt\quad
+1\cdot\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt+x\cdot f(x)\quad-xf(x)\\&=\text{const.}
+\int_0^xf(t)\\g''(x)&=0+f(x).\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes sense! But at the very end I guess you meant f(x) not f(t).

Comment: Also, you may have done a slight mistake in the 3rd.

Comment: @moon1234 Thanks, edited the typo. Don't see the mistake in 3rd so - anyway, you could just as well work from the second line

Comment: Yes, I did and it all comes out well. What did you do with the integral which goes from $x$ to $1$ in the 2nd line?